# Javascript find edit distance not returning correct value

Tags: javascript, recursion, levenshtein-distance, edit-distance

I'm working on a function that computes the edit distance of two strings but according to this only calculator Im getting an incorrect value. Im getting 19 and the calculator is returning 7. Im not sure whats wrong with my program I based it off of *The Algorithm Design Manual*.

```
var recFindEditDistance = function(P, T, i, j) {
    if (i === undefined || j === undefined) return recFindEditDistance(P, T, P.length - 1, T.length - 1);
    if (i === 0 && j === 0) return 0;
    if (i === 0) return j;
    if (j === 0) return i;

    var sub = recFindEditDistance(P, T, i-1, j-1) + (P[i]===T[j] ? 0 : 1);
    var del = recFindEditDistance(P, T, i, j-1) + 1;
    var add = recFindEditDistance(P, T, i-1, j) + 1;

    return Math.max(sub, add, del);
};

console.log(recFindEditDistance('ffadsfsadfasf', 'asdfasdf'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Levenshtein distance algorithm at the every position tries to achieve the **minimum** distance to get to the next position.

[image: Wikipedia recurrence relation]

At the same time, you are trying to get the maximum one :)

Simply change

```
return Math.max(sub, add, del);
```

to

```
return Math.min(sub, add, del);
```

And it will work :)

**Demo:**

```js
function recFindEditDistance(P, T, i, j) {
    if (i === undefined || j === undefined) return recFindEditDistance(P, T, P.length - 1, T.length - 1);
    if (i === 0 && j === 0) return 0;
    if (i === 0) return j;
    if (j === 0) return i;

    var sub = recFindEditDistance(P, T, i-1, j-1) + (P[i]===T[j] ? 0 : 1);
    var del = recFindEditDistance(P, T, i, j-1) + 1;
    var add = recFindEditDistance(P, T, i-1, j) + 1;

    return Math.min(sub, add, del);
};

document.body.innerText = recFindEditDistance('ffadsfsadfasf', 'asdfasdf');
```

Answer (score 0):

I fully realize that this question is quite old and I am posting this just because it apperead in a google search of mine. Even though Yeldar Kurmangaliyev's accepted answer is correctly answering the question at hand, it has to be noted that the above solution is still suffering from at least 2 flaws:

1. It is not handling all the cases properly - it won't work for strings which differ only in their first symbol: e.g. it will wrongly return a distance of 0 for the strings `can` and `pan`. To fix that we can do the following:

> ```
> function recFindEditDistance(P, T, i, j) {
>     if (i === undefined || j === undefined) return recFindEditDistance(P, T, P.length - 1, T.length - 1);
>     if (i === 0 && j === 0) return (P.charAt(i) === T.charAt(j)) ? 0 : 1;
>     if (i === 0) return j;
>     if (j === 0) return i;
>     var sub = recFindEditDistance(P, T, i-1, j-1) + (P[i]===T[j] ? 0 : 1);
>     var del = recFindEditDistance(P, T, i, j-1) + 1;
>     var add = recFindEditDistance(P, T, i-1, j) + 1;
>     return Math.min(sub, add, del);
> };
>
> console.log(recFindEditDistance('can', 'can'));
> ```

2. It is not efficient since the recursion will go through many same sub-problems many times, e.g.: we might solve `recFindEditDistance(P, T, 3, 2)` many times. We don't need to do that since the result is deterministic and once we find a solution for a particular sub-problem we don't need to calculate it again. Since finding the Levenstein distance is a dynamic programming problem, to deal with this we can use techniques such as [memoizatation or tabulation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tabulation-vs-memoizatation/). For a full fletched solution using tabulation, see [here](https://github.com/trekhleb/javascript-algorithms/blob/master/src/algorithms/string/levenshtein-distance/levenshteinDistance.js)